# Magento store home page missing

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.4

I am working on a magento store, i have done some change in the admin panel like scope change in store, and update some project using CSV file after that i am seeing a different as a default page on my store.

if i type domain.com/cms  correct page is coming, but if i type domain.com page is not correct and it is also without js and css, and not able to if the page in the cms/pages,

also tried system> configuration> design and web chages, but it vain,  also tried categories > url rewtire but no luck.

can anybody help me on this.

Comment: I think you need to read [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your question. And highlight paths and keywords.

Comment: my default home page is not correct, if i type mydomain.com/cms then the correct page is coming and if i type exact url like mydomain.com it is going to some other page that i am not able to track ,

Comment: create your  home page on backend cms->pages and give id as home

Comment: I have created but it is still not working, one thing more, if on the path hint from back it is not working on home page only but working on entire website.